# Error in reading serial data in linux in C?

Tags: c, linux

Can anyone please help me with the code I am using to read data from Serial device because I am getting wrong data and the data should be constant but it is changing every time I am executing the program. The correct output is `25 4f 00 16`. The data I am receiving is `8 4 8a 9` .

I have noticed a strange thing also that before displaying the data if I run a while(1) loop with nothing inside it, then I receive the correct data. Why is this happening.? Why am I not  getting correct output.?

So I want to know:

1.Why I am receiving wrong data when I am receiving the correct data on cutecom(serial terminal)

2. Why is the data changing whenever I execute the code.
3. Why I have to use while(1) in code to get correct data

Please help.

CODE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

#define portname "/dev/ttyUSB7"

int set_interface_attribs (int fd, int speed, int parity)
{
        struct termios tty;
        memset (&tty, 0, sizeof tty);
        if (tcgetattr (fd, &tty) != 0)
        {
                // error_message ("error %d from tcgetattr", errno);
                printf("error opening the device");
                return -1;
        }

        cfsetospeed (&tty, speed);
        cfsetispeed (&tty, speed);

        tty.c_cflag = (tty.c_cflag & ~CSIZE) | CS8;     // 8-bit chars
        // disable IGNBRK for mismatched speed tests; otherwise receive break
        // as \000 chars
        tty.c_iflag &= ~IGNBRK;         // disable break processing
        tty.c_lflag = 0;                // no signaling chars, no echo,
                                    // no canonical processing
        tty.c_oflag = 0;                // no remapping, no delays
        tty.c_cc[VMIN]  = 0;            // read doesn't block
        tty.c_cc[VTIME] = 5;            // 0.5 seconds read timeout

        tty.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY); // shut off xon/xoff ctrl

        tty.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);// ignore modem controls,
                                    // enable reading
        tty.c_cflag &= ~(PARENB | PARODD);      // shut off parity
        tty.c_cflag |= parity;
        tty.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
        tty.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;

        if (tcsetattr (fd, TCSANOW, &tty) != 0)
        {
            // error_message ("error %d from tcsetattr", errno);
            printf("error opening the device");
            return -1;
        }
        return -1;
}

int set_blocking (int fd, int should_block)
{
        struct termios tty;
        memset (&tty, 0, sizeof tty);
        if (tcgetattr (fd, &tty) != 0)
        {
            //error_message ("error %d from tggetattr", errno);
            printf("error opening the device");

        }

        tty.c_cc[VMIN]  = should_block ? 1 : 0;
        tty.c_cc[VTIME] = 5;            // 0.5 seconds read timeout

        if (tcsetattr (fd, TCSANOW, &tty) != 0)
          //  error_message ("error %d setting term attributes", errno);

            printf("error opening the device");
    return -1;
}

int main()
{


    int fd = open (portname, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_SYNC);
    if (fd < 0)
    {

            printf("error opening the device");

    }

    set_interface_attribs (fd, B9600, 0);
    set_blocking (fd, 0);


    unsigned char receivebuffer[4] ; //Storing the values in receivebuffer

    read (fd, receivebuffer, sizeof receivebuffer); //reading the data
    //while(1)
     // {
     //  }

    printf(" values are %x %x %x %x \n\n",receivebuffer[3],receivebuffer[2],receivebuffer[1],receivebuffer[0]) //printing the received data in hex format;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that read() returns a value.   You MUST take that into account.  Just because you ask for 4 chars does not mean that read() will return all 4 in one call.

Comment: How can I deal with the that value.? you mean to say I should use a for loop 4 times and check for the value.?

Comment: Check for the return value of `read()` other alternative is to use `recv()` with flag.

Comment: @user4402433 it is returning value `1` . what does that mean.?

Comment: It reads only one character. Check this link <http://linux.die.net/man/2/read>  for further clarification . Try with `recv()`

Comment: If I am receiving one character, then why I am getting `8 4 8a 59`

Comment: Is the baudrate right?
You are not getting `8 4 8a 59` if `read()` returns `1`. You are getting `8` and `4 8a 59` are garbage.

Comment: @gbuzogany - look at the printf arguments - I think the 9 is correct and the 8,4,8a are the garbage?

Comment: baudrate is right and yes 59 is correct but next time I execute  the code, it gives me something else. When I use while(1) loop and then read it gives me correct values, do you have any idea.?

Comment: @MartinJames Yep, it's inverted. But in this case `59` is what was read and `8 4 8a` are garbage.

Comment: Also of note - 9 is the low-order byte of 0x25 ......

Comment: @gbuzogany why I am getting garbage value, when I am receiving correct data in cutecom.?

Comment: The serial port has buffers that are valid just through an interval of time. Maybe the first read you are doing is corrupt (serial port was not ready when you read), and you should just ignore it. Otherwise, try to use a blocking read (instead of non-blocking), or make sure the serial port is read when you read it.

Comment: @gbuzogany what happens in case of blocking mode, does it block garbage value and send correct data?

Comment: Make sure you understand what is going on: http://www.cmrr.umn.edu/~strupp/serial.html

Comment: Is error_message defined in a standard library in the above?